# Custom scikit-learn pickling doesn't work inside a grid search

Tags: serialization, scikit-learn, keras, pickle

I have written a scikit-learn estimator. It has a parameter and a `model_` attribute that is set by `fit`.

```
class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, param="default"):
        self.param = param
        self.model_ = None

    def fit(self, x, y):
        # Sets the value of self.model_
```

I want to be able to pickle `MyEstimator`, but the `model_` object I create cannot be serialized with pickle because it is a [keras](https://keras.io/) model. Following the example of the blog post "[Pickling Keras Models](http://zachmoshe.com/2017/04/03/pickling-keras-models.html)" I added the following pickling handler methods to my class.

```
class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __getstate__(self):
        state = super().__getstate__().copy()
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".hdf5", delete=True) as fd:
            keras.models.save_model(self.model_, fd.name, overwrite=True)
            state["model_"] = fd.read()
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        super().__setstate__(state)
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".hdf5", delete=True) as fd:
            fd.write(state["model_"])
            fd.flush()
            self.__dict__["model_"] = keras.models.load_model(fd.name)
```

This replaces the unpickleable `model_` member with a representation generated by keras' serializer that can be pickled. Using this customization I can call `fit`, serialize and deserialize, and get back my original model. Everything works.

```
e = MyEstimator()
e.fit(x, y)
with open("myfile.pk", mode="wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(e, f)
with open("myfile.pk", mode="rb") as f:
    pickle.load(f) # Returns a copy of e
```

However, serialization does not work when I try to put `MyEstimator` in a [pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) and pickle the result of a [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).

```
s = GridSearchCV(Pipeline([
    # ...
    ("estimator", MyEstimator())
    # ...
    ]))
s.fit(x, y)
with open("myfile.pk", mode="wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(s, f)
```

During the `pickle.dump` call I expect to see `MyEstimator.__getstate__` get called with a fitted `self.model_` object. (This is what happens when I serialize the model by itself, outside the grid search.) Instead `self.model_` is `None`, so I am unable to serialize the `best_estimator_` generated by my grid search.

It looks like grid search serialization is instantiating a new `MyEstimator` object instead of using the one that was in the pipeline. This seems wrong to me. I've looked through the scikit-learn code, but can't see where this is happening.

Is this a bug in scikit-learn, or am I doing something wrong?

(Note: keras does have a [wrapper layer](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/) that can convert some keras models into scikit-learn estimators, but I can't use that here for other reasons and I'm not sure it wouldn't just have the same problem.)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4274

Comment: Mostly all model evaluation tools in scikit like `cross_val_score`, `GridSearchCV` etc clone the given estimator before fitting them. In GridSearchCV, you can see the [source code here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L557) that it clones it.

Comment: Pointing out that particular line of source code helps. I was stepping through this process in the debugger and got lost. I don't understand why after search has completed there would be any clones that hadn't had `fit` called on them though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search object contains a mixed of `MyEstimator` objects, some of which have not had `fit` called on them. The fix is to check if `model_` is `None` before trying to serialize it with the keras tools.

```
class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __getstate__(self):
        state = super().__getstate__().copy()
        if self.model_ is not None:
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".hdf5", delete=True) as fd:
                keras.models.save_model(self.model_, fd.name, overwrite=True)
                state["model_"] = fd.read()
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        super().__setstate__(state)
        if self.model_ is not None:
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".hdf5", delete=True) as fd:
                fd.write(state["model_"])
                fd.flush()
                self.__dict__["model_"] = keras.models.load_model(fd.name)
```

I don't know why there would be any unfitted models in the search object after the grid search had completed, but there are.

Comment: Are you trying to pickle the whole `GridSearchCV` object or just the `GridSearchCV.best_estimator_` (which is essentially what you want)

Comment: I'm trying to pickle the entire search object. I know that `GridSearchCV.best_estimator_` is what I'll use at test time, but I also want to compare the cross-validation scores for various hyperparameter settings.